# 1 large json file to many individual markdown files

Tags: json, graphql, markdown

This was a long post with context, but the gist of it was that I have one 2000 item json file with multiple fields , and I need to make them all become their own markdown files, converting every internal field but the definition item into frontmatter. If I could delete the content item as well, that would be a bonus.

How do I go about this? I've been bashing my head against the wall for three days now.

```
{
"3350" : {
    "askedHistPercent1" : "98",
    "askedHistYear1" : "2009",
    "author" : " Name ",
    "categories" : [ "Generic Category" ],
    "content" : "<p><br />\n</p>\n<div id=\"sidebar\">\n<div class=\"widget\">\n<div class=\"title\">\n<h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Keyword_history\">Keyword history</span></h2>\n</div>\n<table class=\"wikitable\">\n<tr>\n<th> Percentage correct\n</th>\n<td> 98%\n</td></tr>\n<tr>\n<th> Year asked\n</th>\n<td> 2009\n</td></tr></table>\n</div>\n<div class=\"widget\">\n<div class=\"title\">\n<h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Suggest_a_change\">Suggest a change</span><span class=\"mw-editsection\"><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">[</span>edit</a><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">]</span></span></h2>\n</div>\n<p><a rel=\"nofollow\" class=\"external text\" href=\"//www.openanesthesia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:PostToApi&kid=1012\">Suggest a change for this keyword</a>\n</p>\n</div>\n<div class=\"visualClear\"></div>\n</div>\n\n<!-- \nNewPP limit report\nCPU time usage: 0.061 seconds\nReal time usage: 0.065 seconds\nPreprocessor visited node count: 68/1000000\nPreprocessor generated node count: 624/1000000\nPost‐expand include size: 840/2097152 bytes\nTemplate argument size: 241/2097152 bytes\nHighest expansion depth: 5/40\nExpensive parser function count: 0/10000\n-->\n\n<!-- Saved in parser cache with key openanes_wiki:pcache:idhash:3245-0!*!*!!en!*!* and timestamp 20141210132538 and revision id 7678\n -->\n",
    "date" : "2013-05-30 02:23:04",
    "definition" : "<p>Very long definition section;</p>",
    "excerpt" : "Keyword history Percentage correct 98% Year asked 2009 Suggest a change[edit] Suggest a change for this keyword",
    "id" : 3356,
    "permalink" : "",
    "sourceLink1" : "Source",
    "title" : "Title item name"
  }, 
 "3351" : {
    "askedHistPercent1" : "98",
    "askedHistYear1" : "2009",
    "author" : " Name ",
    "categories" : [ "Generic Category" ],
    "content" : "<p><br />\n</p>\n<div id=\"sidebar\">\n<div class=\"widget\">\n<div class=\"title\">\n<h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Keyword_history\">Keyword history</span></h2>\n</div>\n<table class=\"wikitable\">\n<tr>\n<th> Percentage correct\n</th>\n<td> 98%\n</td></tr>\n<tr>\n<th> Year asked\n</th>\n<td> 2009\n</td></tr></table>\n</div>\n<div class=\"widget\">\n<div class=\"title\">\n<h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Suggest_a_change\">Suggest a change</span><span class=\"mw-editsection\"><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">[</span>edit</a><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">]</span></span></h2>\n</div>\n<p><a rel=\"nofollow\" class=\"external text\" href=\"//www.openanesthesia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:PostToApi&kid=1012\">Suggest a change for this keyword</a>\n</p>\n</div>\n<div class=\"visualClear\"></div>\n</div>\n\n<!-- \nNewPP limit report\nCPU time usage: 0.061 seconds\nReal time usage: 0.065 seconds\nPreprocessor visited node count: 68/1000000\nPreprocessor generated node count: 624/1000000\nPost‐expand include size: 840/2097152 bytes\nTemplate argument size: 241/2097152 bytes\nHighest expansion depth: 5/40\nExpensive parser function count: 0/10000\n-->\n\n<!-- Saved in parser cache with key openanes_wiki:pcache:idhash:3245-0!*!*!!en!*!* and timestamp 20141210132538 and revision id 7678\n -->\n",
    "date" : "2013-05-30 02:23:04",
    "definition" : "<p>Very long definition section;</p>",
    "excerpt" : "Keyword history Percentage correct 98% Year asked 2009 Suggest a change[edit] Suggest a change for this keyword",
    "id" : 3356,
    "permalink" : "",
    "sourceLink1" : "Source",
    "title" : "Title item name"
  },
  "3356" : {
    "askedHistPercent1" : "98",
    "askedHistYear1" : "2009",
    "author" : " Name ",
    "categories" : [ "Generic Category" ],
    "content" : "<p><br />\n</p>\n<div id=\"sidebar\">\n<div class=\"widget\">\n<div class=\"title\">\n<h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Keyword_history\">Keyword history</span></h2>\n</div>\n<table class=\"wikitable\">\n<tr>\n<th> Percentage correct\n</th>\n<td> 98%\n</td></tr>\n<tr>\n<th> Year asked\n</th>\n<td> 2009\n</td></tr></table>\n</div>\n<div class=\"widget\">\n<div class=\"title\">\n<h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Suggest_a_change\">Suggest a change</span><span class=\"mw-editsection\"><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">[</span>edit</a><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">]</span></span></h2>\n</div>\n<p><a rel=\"nofollow\" class=\"external text\" href=\"//www.openanesthesia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:PostToApi&kid=1012\">Suggest a change for this keyword</a>\n</p>\n</div>\n<div class=\"visualClear\"></div>\n</div>\n\n<!-- \nNewPP limit report\nCPU time usage: 0.061 seconds\nReal time usage: 0.065 seconds\nPreprocessor visited node count: 68/1000000\nPreprocessor generated node count: 624/1000000\nPost‐expand include size: 840/2097152 bytes\nTemplate argument size: 241/2097152 bytes\nHighest expansion depth: 5/40\nExpensive parser function count: 0/10000\n-->\n\n<!-- Saved in parser cache with key openanes_wiki:pcache:idhash:3245-0!*!*!!en!*!* and timestamp 20141210132538 and revision id 7678\n -->\n",
    "date" : "2013-05-30 02:23:04",
    "definition" : "<p>Very long definition section;</p>",
    "excerpt" : "Keyword history Percentage correct 98% Year asked 2009 Suggest a change[edit] Suggest a change for this keyword",
    "id" : 3356,
    "permalink" : "",
    "sourceLink1" : "Source",
    "title" : "Title item name"
  },
}
```

Current direction. It's hideous, but this is getting me the frontmatter I need. Next I need to figure out how to append only the description part of the data.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const YAML = require("yamljs");
// const json2md = require("./json2md.js");
const bigObject = require("./data1.json");

// var showdown = require("showdown"),
//   converter = new showdown.Converter(),
//   text = "# hello, markdown!",
//   html = converter.makeHtml(text);

Object.entries(bigObject).forEach(([name, data]) => {
  fs.writeFile(`${name}.yaml`, "---\r\n", err => {
    fs.appendFile(`${name}.yaml`, YAML.stringify(data), err => {
      fs.appendFile(`${name}.yaml`, "---\r\n", err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`${name}.yaml has been saved!`);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Output of one file that I did by hand after converting using a website to markdown. It usually consists of everything being hidden in the frontmatter, while the definition tab is displayed inside of the main body

3350.md

```
---
title: ATitleNameHere
categories: Category1
property: 3350
id: 3350
date: 2013-05-30
author: Author Name
description: Category1
askedHistPercent1: 75
askedHistPercent2: 76
askedHistYear1: 2012
askedHistYear2: 2009
assocMediaLink1: Optional section here
assocMediaCaption1: Second Optional section here
---


Definition item here. Usually quite long.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Specifically, what are you having trouble with? Do you know how to read JSON and iterate through the data? Do you know how to output Markdown for each section? Please read [ask]. (Also, that's not valid JSON. It looks like it should probably be wrapped in a top-level `{}` to make it one big object.)

Comment: Ah hello Chris. You are right, I forgot to add the top brackets in there when I copied some of the data. And I'm having trouble iterating through the data. I've found fs, which I believe holds the answer, and am now trying to put together something that will take the large json object, convert it to markdown, and then save it to hopefully the name of that json segment. It is very non-functional, bu tI think this is the right direction?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you would like your output to look like, for just one of your input JSON objects?

Comment: Absolutely. Added onto the end of the above items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const YAML = require("yamljs");
const bigObject = require("./1111data.json.js");
var _ = require("lodash");

Object.entries(bigObject).forEach(([name, data]) => {
  fs.writeFile(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md`, "---\r\n", err => {
    fs.appendFile(
      `${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md`,
      YAML.stringify(data),
      err => {
        fs.appendFile(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md`, "\r\n---\r\n", err => {
          // fs.appendFile(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md`, YAML.stringify(data.definition), err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`${_.kebabCase(data.title)}.md has been saved!`);
          // });
        });
      }
    );
  });
});
```